# GitHub static pages unable to retrieve files

Tags: github, github-pages

I'm not sure what's going on, but it appears that certain .css files are being retrieved and some others are being denied. Anyone have any clues?

Repo: [Code Mirror Themes](https://github.com/FarhadG/codeMirror-themes)

Demo: [Code Mirror Themes Demo](http://farhadg.github.io/codeMirror-themes/)

You can see that certain .css files work, when you toggle the various themes. I would highly doubt there is a limitation on the number of requests for these static pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few css which show up in a Network view as 404 not found.

[image: 404 on htlm css]

That means they are not present in the [`codeMirror-themes/tree/gh-pages/themes`](https://github.com/FarhadG/codeMirror-themes/tree/gh-pages/themes) (`gh-page` branch).

For instance, you see in that `gh-pages` branch a `Tubster.css`, not a `tubster.css`.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. Somehow in the generation process, the file names were not being converted. Fixed! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @FarhadG Excellent! Are you aware of http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer?